# Count Total Indexes of Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with the following structure:

```
    Array
    (
        [DigitalAssets] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [PartNumber] => 0276S-4
                [Link] => https://1ddf4b1b856a39e33863-d785dc0e3b62b5e0ef07f55db00b0659.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/Holley/0576s-4.jpg
                [AssetTypeCode] => P04
                [FileName] => 0576s-4.jpg
                [RecordModifiedDate] => 2020-05-13T18:59:10.28
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [PartNumber] => 0437S-4
                [Link] => https://1ddf4b1b856a39e33863-d785dc0e3b62b5e0ef07f55db00b0659.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/Holley/0437s-4.jpg
                [AssetTypeCode] => P04
                [FileName] => 0437s-4.jpg
                [RecordModifiedDate] => 2020-05-13T18:59:11.687
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [PartNumber] => 0574S-4
                [Link] => https://1ddf4b1b856a39e33863-d785dc0e3b62b5e0ef07f55db00b0659.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/Holley/0574s-4.jpg
                [AssetTypeCode] => P04
                [FileName] => 0574s-4.jpg
                [RecordModifiedDate] => 2020-05-13T18:59:12.593
            )
```

I want to count the total Indexes of array so that I will run loop accordingly. I used Count($array) and Count ($array,RECURSIVE) but it cannot return the correct total number of indexes.

Can only guide that how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you want to count?  The number of nested elements, the number of elements in `DigitalAssets`?  You also could use `foreach()` instead.

Comment: You have an array nested into an array here. Your outer level only has _one_ entry, that under the key `DigitalAssets`. And the array under _that_ key than in turn has multiple entries, which you can count with a simple `count()` … you just need to move to the correct level first.

Comment: Yes I want to count the total index numbers in DigitalAssets Array.

Comment: @cbroe: Can you provide an example?

Comment: What, the mere counting? That has already been answered. And if you just want to loop over all times, then you don’t necessarily need to count them first, you can also use a `foreach` loop, as Nigel already said. (All in all, this is stuff you should be learning from a beginner tutorial, rather than ask about here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You want to count `DigitalAssets` direct children You can do this
`count($array['DigitalAssets'])`

Here are some tests how `count` should work.

Code is:

```
$test = array
        (
            'DigitalAssets' => array
            (
                0 => array(
                    'PartNumber' => '0276S-4',
                    'Link' => 'https://1ddf4b1b856a39e33863-d785dc0e3b62b5e0ef07f55db00b0659.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/Holley/0576s-4.jpg',
                    'AssetTypeCode' => 'P04',
                    'FileName' => '0576s-4.jpg',
                    'RecordModifiedDate' => '2020-05-13T18:59:10.28'
                ),
                1 => array(
                    'PartNumber' => '0437S-4',
                    'Link' => 'https://1ddf4b1b856a39e33863-d785dc0e3b62b5e0ef07f55db00b0659.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/Holley/0437s-4.jpg',
                    'AssetTypeCode' => 'P04',
                    'FileName' => '0437s-4.jpg',
                    'RecordModifiedDate' => '2020-05-13T18:59:11.687'
                ),
                2 => array
                (
                    'PartNumber' => '0574S-4',
                    'Link' => 'https://1ddf4b1b856a39e33863-d785dc0e3b62b5e0ef07f55db00b0659.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/Holley/0574s-4.jpg',
                    'AssetTypeCode' => 'P04',
                    'FileName' => '0574s-4.jpg',
                    'RecordModifiedDate' => '2020-05-13T18:59:12.593'
                )
            )
        );

        echo count($test['DigitalAssets'])." ".count($test['DigitalAssets'], 0)." ".count($test['DigitalAssets'], 1);
        exit();
```

Result in my case:
`3 3 18`

This means taht in my case `mode` in count is set to 0 by default so i will get only first level counted. If i set mode to 1 i will get all nested items counted as well. This should clear things up for You.

Comment: i think he is talking about   foreach($array['DigitalAssets'] as $value)  {
     $indexes += count($value);
 }

Comment: @Milan Rilex Ristic: When I echo $indexes it gives empty result. I just want to echo the count of total indexes in an array.

Comment: define it first  like $indexes=array(); in parent scope

Comment: @Milan Rilex Ristic: with your code in first comment, I receive result 4025 because array has total 804 indexes. And each index has 5 values as I mentioned in my code. I need result 804 to be displayed instead of 4025

Comment: Please try with seccond option set to 0 in `count` function use, from php manual:
`If the optional mode parameter is set to COUNT_RECURSIVE (or 1), count() will recursively count the array. This is particularly useful for counting all the elements of a multidimensional array.`